# Is the following helper class thread safe?

Tags: c#, thread-safety

I need to keep track of a sequential Id, this is being returned to me via a SP which is doing a max(id) across 4 tables, there is no identifer/sequence in the db which is managing the sequence. This will obviously have concurrency issues so i created a helper class to ensure unique Id's are always generated.

The helper is initialised via its repository, which initially calls the DB to find the current Id, all subsequent requests for an Id are serviced in memory via the helper. There will only ever be 1 app using the DB (mine) so i dont need to worry about someone else coming along and creating transactions & throwing the Id out of sync. I think ive got the basics of thread-saftey but im worried about a race condition when the helper is initialised, can someone please advise :)

```
private class TransactionIdProvider
{
private static readonly object Accesslock = new object();
private int _transactionId;
public int NextId
{
    get
    {
        lock (Accesslock)
        {
            if(!Initialised) throw new Exception("Must Initialise with id first!!");
            return _transactionId++;
        }
    }
}

public bool Initialised { get; private set; }

public void SetId(int id)
{
    lock (Accesslock)
    {
        if (Initialised) return;
        _transactionId = id;
        Initialised = true;
    }
}

public TransactionIdProvider()
{
    Initialised = false;
}
}
```

The helper class is initialised in a repository:

```
private static readonly TransactionIdProvider IdProvider = new TransactionIdProvider();

    public int GetNextTransactionId()
    {
        if(!IdProvider.Initialised)
        {
            // Ask the DB
            int? id = _context.GetNextTransactionId().First();
            if (!id.HasValue)
                throw new Exception("No transaction Id returned");
            IdProvider.SetId(id.Value);
        }

        return IdProvider.NextId;
    }
```

Comment: Is there more than one repository using this ?

Comment: Don't declare `AccessLock` as `static` when `_transactionId` is not. And using the same naming scheme would help too.

Comment: I use Pascal case for fields that are readonly / constants and _Camel case for the rest fields. Only 1 repository is using the class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is thread-safe, but it's unnecessarily slow.
You don't need a lock to just increment a number; instead, you can use atomic math.

Also, you're sharing the lock across all instances (it's `static`), which is unnecessary.  (There's nothing wrong with having two different instances run at once)

Finally, (IMHO) there is no point in having a separate uninitialized state.

I would write it like this:

```
class TransactionIdProvider {
    private int nextId;
    public TransactionIdProvider(int id) {
        nextId = value;
    }

    public int GetId() {
        return Interlocked.Increment(ref nextId);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 because your code is a lot more concise and readable. But the speed difference seems irrelevant.

Comment: Nice; simple, clean, minimal, elegant, and lock-free.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is thread-safe; however, IMO the lock is too global - a static lock to protect instance data smacks a bit of overkill.

Also, NextId as a property is bad - it changes state, so should be a method.

You might also prefer Interlocked.Increment over a lock, although that changes most of the class.

Finally, in the SetId - if it is already initialised I would throw an exception (InvalidOperationException) rather than blindly ignore the call - that sounds like an error. Of course, that then introduces a tricky interval between checking Initialized and calling SetId - you could just hAve SetId return true if it made the change, and false if it turned out to be initialized at the point of set, but SLaks' approach is nicer.

Comment: That was where i was worrying about a race condition. Its a web app so multiple repository instances (repo created per request) could call GetNextTransactionId(). I reasoned that if its initialised then i dont care, just continue and get an Id as the helper will guarantee uniqueness

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a good idea, you should find another way to deal with this.
Usually when really unique ids are required and there is no a way computationally valid to check if the id is used, i would use a GUID.

However you can just use interlocked operations instead of locking, you can do it without locking at all.

Look for Interlocked.Increment, Interlocked.Exchange and Interlocked.CompareExchange

```
private class TransactionIdProvider
{
    private volatile int _initialized;
    private int _transactionId;

    public int NextId
    {
        get
        {
            for (;;)
            {
                switch (_initialized)
                {
                    case 0: throw new Exception("Not initialized");
                    case 1: return Interlocked.Increment(ref _transactionId);
                    default: Thread.Yield();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void SetId(int id)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _initialized, -1, 0) == 0)
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _transactionId, id);
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref _initialized, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you a warning, but it is normal and is also reported in C# documentation as legal. So ignore that warning with a nice pragma:

```
// Disable warning "A reference to a volatile field will not be treated as volatile"
#pragma warning disable 0420
```

If you don't need to check for IsInitialized you can do it in the simplest possible way:

```
public int NextId()
{
    return Interlocked.Increment(ref _transactionId);
}

public void Set(int value)
{
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref _transactionId, value);
}
```